# Property in generic base class with different implementation

Tags: c#, generics, properties

I've got an abstract class `CommandBase<T, X>` that I want to have a property `InnerCommand`.

But since the `InnerCommand` might have other types for T and X than the command that contains it, how can I define that?

The abstract class:

```
public abstract class CommandBase<T, X>
    where T : CommandResultBase
    where X : CommandBase<T, X>
{
    public CommandBase<T, X> InnerCommand { get; set; }
    (...)
}
```

In the example above `InnerCommand` will only accept instances that have the same types for T and X, but I need to allow for other types.

An AddOrderitemCommand:

```
public class AddOrderitemCommand : CommandBase<AddOrderitemResult, AddOrderitemCommand>
{
    (...)
}
```

Might contain a WebserviceCommand:

```
public class GetMenuCommand : CommandBase<GetMenuResult,GetMenuCommand>
{
    (...)
}
```

Please advise on the syntax for allowing this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You basically have three options:

1. Use `dynamic` as the type of that property. Nothing I would do.
2. Use `object` as the type of that property. Nothing I would do.
3. Create a non-generic base class or interface for commands. Make `CommandBase<T, X>` implement it and use it as the type of the property. That's the way I would go.

Comment: 3 is fine; I think 1 & 2 make the API *too* open - you could assign `"some string"`, for example - plus it isn't obvious from the signature what it expects

Comment: @MarcGravell: I agree. That's why I wouldn't use them. But it is still a possibility, so I wanted to mention it. There might be some very constrained scenarios where it might make sense to use them.

Answer (score 6):

If the `InnerCommand` doesn't relate to the parent `T`/`X`, then I would suggest using a non-generic `InnerCommand` that doesn't advertise the type in the signature. This may mean adding a non-generic base-type (`CommandBase`) or an interface (`ICommandBase`). Then you can simply use:

```
public ICommandBase InnerCommand {get;set;}
// note : CommandBase<T,X> : ICommandBase
```

or

```
public CommandBase InnerCommand {get;set;}
// note : CommandBase<T,X> : CommandBase
```